# How to make div of a frame over frame other?

Tags: css, frame, frameset

I have two frame in a frameset:

```
<frameset rows="410,*" cols="*" id=AWindow framespacing="2" border="1">
    <frame src="/MarketWatch/MenuMW" name="Header" id="Header">
      <div class="dvOver"></div>
    </frame>
    <frame src="/MarketWatch/OrderForm" name="Order" id="Order"></frame>
</frameset>
```

I want make div "dvOver" over two frame.
[image]
Help me, please! Thank you!

Comment: See if it works out with z-index css property...

Comment: dvOver is within frame or outside frame?

Comment: Hi @Pranjal, z-index not work.

Comment: Hi @SanjeevK, I want dvOver of frame Header over frame Oder and over frame Header, it same in picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `position: absolute` the object you want to be overflow
Second `z-index: 999` make sure that object is overlab everyone else
Then you can position that object

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/u0rwxvuL/

Comment: Hi @Felix, i use frame not use div.